# Symfony 2.1 + composer + apc

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

When I used composer command "install" or "upload", I had fatal errors such as :

> PHP Fatal error:  include(): Cannot redeclare class...

I solved the problem by changing in my apc.ini (or in your php.ini) :

```
apc.enable_cli = 1
```

to

```
apc.enable_cli = 0
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Adding the error message so people are more likely to find this question when searching by the error message. PHP Fatal error:  include(): Cannot redeclare class composer\command\helper\dialoghelper in phar:///opt/foo/composer.phar/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 150

Answer (score 1):

The composer installer at http://getcomposer.org/download/ should warn you about this - it's the best way to get the composer.phar and be sure your system is setup properly.